# Why does discord bot commands not working on replit

Tags: python, discord, bots, replit

I am trying to create a python discord bot in replit. The code seems to be perfect but when I run the script, it does not give any errors but does not respond to the ">kick @user" in the discord server. I think there is something to do with replit. The code is given below:-

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot_token = os.environ['TOKEN']  # Bot's token stored as an env variable

intent = discord.Intents.all()  # Intents are like permissions of bot

intent.message_content = True  # Permission to read message content

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">", bot=True, intents=intent)

@bot.event  # events are triggered when conditions are met
async def on_ready():  # run when script is ready
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):  # run when recieved a message
  if message.author == bot.user:  # if message is sent by the bot itself
    return

  if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

@bot.command(name="kick")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No Reason"):
    try:
      await user.kick(reason=reason)
      embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.red(),title="", description="")
      embed.add_field(name="Kicked:", value=f"""
        The user **{user}** has been kicked.
        Reason = **{reason}**
      """, inline=True)
      ctx.reply(embed=embed)
    except:
      embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Colour.red(),title="", description="")
      embed.add_field(name="Kicked:", value="""
        Error
      """, inline=True)
    await bot.process_commands(ctx)

bot.run(bot_token)
```

I checked if the kick function is even ran in the first place but it does not.

Comment: Does your bot have the proper permissions?

Comment: do i need to set permissions in the bot developer panel or ask the admin of the server to give kick permission to the bot?

Comment: I already have given it permissions of banning and kicking people and also made it moderator. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to remove the try and except block and write `await bot.process_commands(message)` in the end of the on_message function.